# Copy MultipartFormDataContent or pass it by value / Multiple send request with MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, copy, httpclient, pass-by-value

I'm trying to send a post request with MultipartFormDataContent 2 times in a row.
First time it works correct. But the next time compiler says me MultipartFormDataContent variable has allready disposed.

```
Tlg Tlg = new Tlg("MyToken");
MultipartFormDataContent options = new MultipartFormDataContent();
options.Add(new StringContent("MyChatId"), "chat_id");
options.Add(new StringContent("Hello!"), "text");
Console.WriteLine(Tlg.Send("sendMessage", options: options).Result);//ОК
Console.WriteLine(Tlg.Send("sendMessage", options: options).Result);//Fails
```

Tlg.Send just sends request via httpClient.PostAsync with MultipartFormDataContent variable (options).

How to realize multiple use of the MultipartFormDataContent variable with the least expenses?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I've just pass JObject parameters to function and then create new MultipartFormDataContent every call of function.

```
        MultipartFormDataContent o = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        if(options != null)
        {
            foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)options)
            {
                o.Add(new StringContent((string)x.Value), x.Name);
            }
        }
```

If it would be StreamContent or others, i'll add StreamContent.